# Facebook Application Auth Token Get Error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, get, access-token, facebook-access-token

I am trying to request the authtoken for my app via the Facebook API Graph Exlorer following the facebooks [instructions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/). When I do a get call with a URL with the following form:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials
```

I get the following error:

```
 {
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid callback",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 1
  }
}
```

Suggestions on how I might go about obtaining the access token for my app would be greatly appreciated!

If I try to obtain the access code programmatically running the following code:

```
 FB.api('/oauth/access_token?client_id={APP_ID}&client_secret={APP_SECRET}&grant_type=client_credentials', function(response) {
   alert(JSON.stringify(response));
  });
```

I get the following error:

```
{"error":"load-error: unknown"}
```

Comment: What instructions are you following?

Comment: `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials` works for me

Comment: I added the link to the instructions I'm following above.

Comment: please post more of your code. This part is working OK assuming you pass the correct APP ID and secret.

Comment: I'm not sure what more I can post, other than the App ID and Secret, as I am entering this URL directly into the Graph API Explorer. http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=554718794

Comment: I have also documented an attempt to obtain the token programmatically (see edit).

Comment: I just tried entering the URL directly into my browser and it worked. Still not sure why my two other approaches failed. Do you want me to mark this resolved?

Comment: Same problem here and also same solution, worked from my browser...

Answer (score 6):

You cannot execute this command using the Facebook Graph API explorer. 
Typing it directly into the browser returns the access token as desired.

Comment: Thanks, it's actually OK typing it directly in the browser... This facebook protocol is sometimes very hard to understand...